# Perform Loess smoothing in R by ID?

Tags: r

I have time-series data on multiple individuals:

```
ID Day Weight
1 1 334
1 2 339
1 3 342
1 4 339
2 1 332
2 2 334
2 3 338
2 4 341
```

How can I get the Loess smoothed results by ID? Running Loess smoothing on a single individual:

```
mod <- loess(Weight ~ Day, data=test, span=0.18)

smoothed <- predict(mod)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will allow you to plot the loess curve since that is the default for geom_smooth.

Also facet_wrap allows you to create a separate plot for each ID.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Weight, y=Day))+geom_point()+geom_smooth()+facet_wrap(~ID)
```

If you want it all in one plot:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Weight, y=Day, 
                 col = as.factor(ID), group = as.factor(ID)))+geom_point()+geom_smooth()
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get all lines in a single plot? Right now is is plotting each line in a separate panel. In the real data I have several hundred individuals.

Comment: How about this? If `col` doesn't work try `colour` instead

Comment: @NickKnauer Yes. I couldn't post an answer while you were already this close. Cheers.

Comment: @jwbucha123 `span=0.18` does not work on your sample dataset, probably for the actual dataset.